# Not able to run libgdx android sample in android studio

Tags: android, libgdx

I have followed the instructions in libgdx Setup and generated the 'test' directory  which contains the android sample project . I have imported it successfully ( contains two directory 'android' and 'core' ) but I am not able to run it. Every time this error comes while compiling with
gradle :

[image]

```
android {
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
        compileSdkVersion 22
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        }
    }

    // needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
    tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
        pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
        pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
    }

    // called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
    // the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
    // so they get packed with the APK.
    task copyAndroidNatives() {
        file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
        file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
        file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

        configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
            def outputDir = null
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
            if(outputDir != null) {
                copy {
                    from zipTree(jar)
                    into outputDir
                    include "*.so"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task run(type: Exec) {
        def path
        def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
        if (localProperties.exists()) {
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
                properties.load(instr)
            }
            def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
            if (sdkDir) {
                path = sdkDir
            } else {
                path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
            }
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }

        def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
        commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.mygdx.game.android/com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher'
    }

    // sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
    eclipse {
        // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
        // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
        sourceSets {
            main {
                java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
            }
        }

        jdt {
            sourceCompatibility = 1.6
            targetCompatibility = 1.6
        }

        classpath {
            plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]
            containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
        }

        project {
            name = appName + "-android"
            natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
            buildCommands.clear();
            buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
            buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
            buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
            buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
        }
    }

    // sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
    idea {
        module {
            sourceDirs += file("src");
            scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]

            iml {
                withXml {
                    def node = it.asNode()
                    def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                    builder.current = node;
                    builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                        facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                            configuration {
                                option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

after i add this in

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

then i get this error:

[image]

my build.gradle of core :

```
        apply plugin: "java"

        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

        sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]


        eclipse.project {
            name = appName + "-core"
        }
```

Also in core's build.gradle I get error in :

eclipse not found :

```
      eclipse.project {
            name = appName + "-core"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well It worked , I imported the test in a new project instead of merging the modules in  my already existing  project . And used default gradle wrapper instead of local gradle distribution . 
[image]